# Wordpress Javascript - When a button is clicked, the system should wait and then jump to a section

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dynamic

I have a plugin on my wordpress site which can dynamically show and hide sections.
When I link to the section from the button that performs this action (to scroll), the scroll to the section does not work because the content was still hidden.

So I need a function with which the link in the button is triggered only after x ms to ensure that the section was already expanded.

Comment: This is off topic. Please share the source code you tried to achieve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.